# Can't manipulate media uploads

Tags: uploads, media

I'm trying to change the title of the uploaded image.
But nothing is working, I placed this code in my plugin file:

```
add_filter('sanitize_file_name', 'filter_function_name_11', 10, 2);

function filter_function_name_11($filename, $filename_raw) {  
    $pos = strripos($filename, 'example');
    if ($pos === false) {
       wp_die();
    } else {
        return $filename;
    }
}
```

It does nothing, no error nothing.
I'm really stuck.

The user opens the `wp.media.frames.file_frame`, everything works fine, the image gets uploaded. But I want to change the filename.

Comment: That's because your function does not change anything.

Comment: This code should not upload the image if it doesn't containt **example** in the filename. But that doesn't work.